# Notification is not showing in broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

Notification is not coming even when the app is open or closed. But toast comes only when the app is open.I have a main activity and another class which extends broadcastlistener. In activity I am requesting permissions and in class I have written code for notification to come on incoming calls. Please help me with some code snippets. Below is my activity class.

```
public class PhoneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private static final int REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 1;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone);

    int readContactsPermissionLog = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG);
    if(readContactsPermissionLog != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG}, REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
    }
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
    }
  }
}
```

This is my class which extends broadcastreceiver.

```
public class PhoneState extends BroadcastReceiver {
  public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "10001" ;
  private final static String default_notification_channel_id = "default" ;
  boolean connected  = true;
  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
      String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
      if (state != null) {
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
          if (!intent.getExtras().containsKey(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)) {
            Log.i("Call receiver", "skipping intent=" + intent + ", extras=" + intent.getExtras() + " - no number was supplied");
            return;
          }
          String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
          System.out.println("incoming number is " + number);
          if (number != null) {
            if (number.equals("some number i have given for testing")) {
              System.out.println("number matched");
                           createNotificationChannel(number,context);
          createNotificationChannel(number,context);

              // Toast.makeText(context, "number is " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
          createNotificationChannel(number,context);
            //  Toast.makeText(context, "number is " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              System.out.println("not matched");
            }
          } else {
            System.out.println("number is null");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }




 private void createNotificationChannel(String number,Context context) {
        String CHANNEL_ID = "10";
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
          CharSequence name = "Phone";
          int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
          NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
          channel.setDescription(number);
          // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
          // or other notification behaviors after this
          NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
          notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
      }
```

I have added this in my manifest file.

```
 <receiver android:name=".PhoneState"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And this is my layout activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity.PhoneActivity">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you have android version less than 8, otherwise you should use Notification Channel to create notification
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Answer (score 3):

It may be you do not add Services in your Manifist. In case of activity added automatically by android studio but android do not add services automatically in Manifist.
So you need to add this code in your Manifist.

```
       <service
        android:name=".FireBaseMessagingService.GettingDeviceTokenService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".FireBaseMessagingService.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I Hope that will help you.

Comment: I added it but it didnt help